# Объект не следует за мышью на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, я опять здесь со своими тупыми вопросами...
Не подскажете, что здесь не так?

html:

```
<div class:'move'> </div>
```

css:

```
.move{
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background: black;
border-radius: 50%;
```

js:

```
const move = document.querySelector(".move")
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let xAsis = e.pageX
  let yAsis = e.pageY
  move.style.top = yAsis
  move.style.left = xAsis
})
```

Comment: проблема в js, если выводить `xAsis` и `yAsis`, то все окей, но почему-то не присваиваются стили

Comment: position absolute и в js move.style.top = yAsis + "px"  move.style.left = xAsis + "px"

Comment: Объект не кот ^.^ и за мышами ~0^ бегать не может.

Comment: @MaximLensky  опять забыл `px` добавить, боже. Спасибо

Comment: ну тогда отметьте решением мой ответ - я его дал

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg это тоже верно)

Comment: @Sevastopol' salam , что это такое, есть даже у тебя?  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11505/308951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправил ошибки которые указал в комментарии

```js
const move = document.querySelector(".move")
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let xAsis = e.pageX
  let yAsis = e.pageY
  move.style.top = yAsis + "px"
  move.style.left = xAsis + "px"
})
```

```css
.move {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='move'> </div>
```